# How to show that $A=c I$ means that $f(x)$ is equal to some real number c?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

We have a symmetric matrix $A$ which entries are $a_{ij}$. Also, there is a function $f(x) = \frac{\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$ definded everywhere in $R^n$ except at the origin. How to prove that $f(x) =c$ if $A=c I$. I guess that the most important thing here is that matrix $A$ is symmetric so at some point terms $\frac{\sum_{i,j=1}^n x_ix_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$ somehow cancel out, so c is some sum of coeffients $a_{ij}$, but is still have no idea how to prove it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A = cI$, since $I$ is the identity matrix, all of its diagonal values are $1$ and all of the rest are $0$. Thus, for $1 \le i,j \le n$, you have $a_{ii} = c$ and $a_{ij} = 0$ for $i \neq j$. This means all of the terms except for those where $i = j$ are $0$ in the fraction numerator, so you then get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(x) & = \frac{\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n c(x_i)(x_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \\
& = \frac{c\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \\
& = c
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$